# preg_math multiply responce

Tags: php, preg-match

```
<?php
$string = "Movies and Stars I., 32. part";
$pattern = "((IX|IV|V?I{0,3}[\.]))";

if(preg_match($pattern, $string, $x) == false)
{
    print "NAPAKA!";
}
else
{
    print_r($x);
}
?>
```

And the response is:

```
Array ( [0] => I. [1] => I. )
```

I should get only 1 response... Why do I get multiple responses?

Comment: Because you have multiple parenthesis.

Comment: Stupid mistake.. thanks to all

Comment: What if I want to use this pattern`(( IX|IV|V?I{0,3}[\.])|( M{1,4}[\.]))` and get only one result?

Comment: Got it: `( IX|IV|V?I{0,3}[\.]| M{1,4}[\.])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element at index 0 is the whole matched string. The element at index 1 is the contents of the first capture group, i.e. the content inside the parenthesis. In this case, they just happen to be the same. Just use `$x[0]` to get the value you're looking for.

Comment: What if I want to use this pattern`(( IX|IV|V?I{0,3}[\.])|( M{1,4}[\.]))` and get only one result?

Comment: Don't mind about the amount of keys in the array, just use `$x[0]` and you'll always get the whole matched string, no matter what your pattern is!

Comment: No, I mean `$x[0]`. The first element contains the whole string that was matches, keys `1..n` contain the capture subgroups.

Answer (score 1):

The nested parenthesis should, in this instance, be a "non-capturing" subpattern.

`$pattern = "~((?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3}[\.]))~";`

Try that.  It will tell the regex compiler to not capture the results of those parenthesis into the array.

In fact, looking at your regex, you don't even need those parenthesis.  Make your regex this:

`$pattern = "~IX|IV|V?I{0,3}[\.]~";`

That should also work.

Comment: you forgot delimiters in last pattern

Comment: I think this is what he wants: `/(?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3})[\.]/`

Comment: I know you can use any non-whitespace char as a delimiter but isn't using anything besides the `/` considdered less than desirable? You only substitute the forward slash when you're trying to make a regex with an insane amount of forward slashes in it (when you try to match an url for example)

Comment: @Karolis: I don't think it really matters.  I've always used that as a delimiter without problem.

Comment: @Pete171 I mean not the delimiter, but the place where I used parenthesis. This changes the logic. I think my regex has more sense that the original one.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern has multiple groups in it -> the () brackets tell you what to capture in your match.

Try this:

```
$pattern = "(IX|IV|V?I{0,3}[\.])";
```

If you have a hard time identifying the wanted groups in the result you can name them as specified in the [php.net documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

That would look something like this:

```
$pattern = "(?P<groupname>IX|IV|V?I{0,3}[\.])";
```

Answer (score 0):

You get 0-indexed for all mathced string and result for every paretness `()`. it's helpful to get groups i.e

```
preg_match('~([0-9]+)([a-z]+)','12abc',$x);
$x is ([0]=>12abc [1]=>12 [2]=>abc)
```

In your case you can simply delete `()` (1 pair ot them, 1 pair is used as delimiters)